# unable to access server in jax-rs through 198.168.x in window 8.1

Tags: java, android, window, jax-rs, wildfly-10

Hello Everyone I'm having problem in my android application. I have android app install in ubuntu 16.0.4 which work fine in my work pc but when I imports my app in window 8.1. From login it doesnot work.
First Off My android studio doesn't recognized my mobile in window 8.1 so I have install pdaNet and it work fine. 
when I debug my code
**An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine**
**ConnectivityManager return both true as well as false. It never did in linux**

```
  ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivityManager != null) {
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable()
                && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

I dont know what's the problem with window 8.1 but I connected my mobile with my laptop sharing same wifi and web services run on

```
http://192.168.0.102:8080/payroll-services-ws/api/secured/message
```

and When I checked on Postman, It is working correctly..

So here is my code of login

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

private ProgressBar progressBar;
List<MyTask> myTasksList;
private static final String RESTLOGIN="http://192.168.0.102:8080/payroll-services-ws/api/secured/message";
private EditText usernameEditText;
private EditText passwordEdittext;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    progressBar =(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBarLogin);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    myTasksList = new ArrayList<>();

    usernameEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    passwordEdittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPass);
}

public void onBtnClick(View view){
    Button buttonLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSingIn);
    if (view.getId()==R.id.btnSingIn){
        //updateDisplay();
        if (isOnline()){
            requestData(RESTLOGIN);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Not Connect WIth Network", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    else if (view.getId()==R.id.btnSignUp){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,Register.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
protected boolean isOnline(){
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivityManager != null) {
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable()
                && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
private void requestData(String uri){
    MyTask myTask = new MyTask();
    myTask.execute(uri,usernameEditText.getText().toString(),passwordEdittext.getText().toString());
}
public void updateDisplay(){
    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent mainActivity = new Intent(Login.this,Home.class);
    mainActivity.putExtra("username",usernameEditText.getText().toString());
    mainActivity.putExtra("password",passwordEdittext.getText().toString());
    startActivity(mainActivity);
}
//param progress and result
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        if (myTasksList.size()==0){
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        myTasksList.add(this);
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //param 0 which is come from requestData
        String content = HttpManager.getData(params[0],params[1],params[2]);
        return content;

    }

    //content of dobackground pass to the dopostexcute
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        myTasksList.remove(this);
        if (myTasksList.size()==0){
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        if (result==null){
            Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Sorry Username or password doesnot match",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        //list of object from content
        //from json

        updateDisplay();
    }

}

}
```

**I can only access in postman via localhost:8080**

Comment: What is the problem? The Android code, or the actual server?

Comment: code is fine im sure but i cant access it by using 192.168.0.102:8080 address on both postman and with android

Comment: Okay, when you use postman on the same computer, though, `127.0.0.1`, or `192.168.0.102` just fallback to `127.0.0.1` in the routing table. If you cannot access `192.168.0.102` on a separate device in the LAN, then that is a networking problem. 1) The server must be publicly accessible and 2) The port must be listening, then 3) The firewall must be open to allow the port

Comment: how can I do it??? In server side i have no problem it is working fine in linux.

Comment: I don't know. There is not enough detail here to help, and I don't think the problem is the Android code if it all works in linux.

Comment: thank u sir for ur kind infromation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem occur due to the firewall of window 8.1 are blocking any public IP address, So editing the firewall setting esp TCP 80 port solve the problem for me.